# Detecting dropped connections

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have a server and many clients. Server needs to know when client disconnects ungracefully (doesn't send TCP FIN), so that it doesn't have hanging connection and other disposable objects associated with this client.

Anyway, I read [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) and decided to go with adding a "keepalive message to the application protocol" (contains only header bytes) and "explicit timer assuming the worst" methods from the linked blog.

When client connects (btw I am using TcpListener and TcpClient), server starts a System.Threading.Timer that counts down 30 seconds. Whenever server receives something from that client, it resets the timer. When timer reaches 0, it disconnects user and disposes whatever it needs to dispose. Clients application also has a timer and when user doesn't send anything for 15 seconds (half of the server's value, just to be sure), it sends the keepalive message.

My question is, is there easier way to achieve this? Maybe some option on TcpClient? I tried with TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout, but that doesn't seem to work with ReadAsync.

Comment: as Stephen points out, using heartbeat messages in the application protocol is the only surefire method of ensuring that the connection is alive and that both applications are operating correctly. be warned that many an engineer has created a heartbeat thread that continues to operate even when the application threads have failed. you need to ensure that heartbeats form part of the operating structure of the solution. Its a non trivial problem.

Comment: for asynchronous socket operations, I have turned to this code, which I have used successfully http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx I have used the `SocketAwaitable`

Comment: Thanks! I will try that code, but I didn't quite understand what you meant by "you need to ensure that heartbeats form part of the operating structure of the solution".

Comment: what I mean is that if your solution has one or more threads that send messages and perform business logic, and a separate thread to send heartbeat messages, then it's possible to end up in a situation where the heartbeat messages are being sent, but the application threads have faulted. Ultimately you need to ensure that heartbeat messages are sent only when you are reasonably sure that the application is operating correctly, and no threads have faulted (stopped). The heartbeats should be integrated into the solution fully.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Stephen points out](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) using heartbeat messages in the application protocol is the only surefire method of ensuring that the connection is alive and that both applications are operating correctly. be warned that many an engineer has created a heartbeat thread that continues to operate even when the application threads have failed.

Using the classes [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) will solve your asynchronous socket question.

```
public sealed class SocketAwaitable : INotifyCompletion
{ 
    private readonly static Action SENTINEL = () => { };

    internal bool m_wasCompleted; 
    internal Action m_continuation; 
    internal SocketAsyncEventArgs m_eventArgs;

    public SocketAwaitable(SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs) 
    { 
        if (eventArgs == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("eventArgs"); 
        m_eventArgs = eventArgs; 
        eventArgs.Completed += delegate 
        { 
            var prev = m_continuation ?? Interlocked.CompareExchange(
                ref m_continuation, SENTINEL, null); 
            if (prev != null) prev(); 
        }; 
    }

    internal void Reset() 
    { 
        m_wasCompleted = false; 
        m_continuation = null; 
    }

    public SocketAwaitable GetAwaiter() { return this; }

    public bool IsCompleted { get { return m_wasCompleted; } }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) 
    { 
        if (m_continuation == SENTINEL || 
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(
                ref m_continuation, continuation, null) == SENTINEL) 
        { 
            Task.Run(continuation); 
        } 
    }

    public void GetResult() 
    { 
        if (m_eventArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success) 
            throw new SocketException((int)m_eventArgs.SocketError); 
    } 
}
```